# lower bound of certain function $\Psi$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $g$ be a nonnegative nonincreasing radial function on $\mathbb R^d$. Define  $$ \psi(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \left( 1 - \cos(\xi \cdot z) \right) g(|z|) \ dz, \quad \Psi(R) = \sup_{|\xi|\le R} \psi(\xi) . $$ 
I want to show that $g(r) r^d \le C \Psi(1/r), \ r>0 $ for some constant $C>0$. I tried to take a lower bound $C'$ of $1-\cos(\xi \cdot z)$ for $|z| \le r$, so that $\psi(\xi) \ge \int_{|z|\le r} C' g(|z|) \ dz \ge C'' g(r) r^d \ (\because |B(0,r)| \propto r^d)$, but couldn't find such $C'$. What argument do I have to use for this ineqaulity?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Psi(1/r)\ge \sup_{1/(2r)\le |\xi|\le 1/r}\psi(\xi)$ you can assume that $1/(2r)\le |\xi|\le 1/r$. Since everything is nonnegative, using spherical coordinates for any such $\xi$ you have
\begin{align}
\psi(\xi)\ge\int_{r/2}^r\int_{\partial B(0,1)}(1-cos(\xi\cdot t z))d\sigma(z) t^{d-1}g(t) dt\\
\ge g(r)\int_{r/2}^r\int_{E_{\xi}}(1-cos(\xi\cdot t z))d\sigma(z) t^{d-1} dt,
\end{align}
where $E_\xi=\{z\in \partial B(0,1):\,  \frac14 \le\frac{\xi}{|\xi|}\cdot z\le \frac12\}$. Since $1/(2r)\le |\xi|\le 1/r$ and $r/2\le t\le t$ you have $1/4\le t|\xi|\le 1$. Hence for $z\in E_\xi$ you get that $\xi\cdot t z=t|\xi|\frac{\xi}{|\xi|}\cdot z\in [1/(16),1/2]$. This implies that $1-cos(\xi\cdot t z)\ge c>0$ for some constant independent of $\xi$ and $r$ and $t$. It follows that 
\begin{align}
\psi(\xi)\ge c \text{ meas}(E_\xi) g(r) \int_{r/2}^r t^{d-1} dt=c\text{ meas}(E_\xi) g(r) \frac1d (r^d-(r/2)^d),
\end{align}
where $\text{meas}(E_\xi)$ is the surface measure of the sector $E_\xi$, which is a constant independent of $\xi$. Probably a bit too complicated....but..